# How to add start time to a YouTube playlist that uses listType

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

As seen working here: https://jsfiddle.net/spqf729t/

This is the embed player, works here

```
<iframe width="442" height="261" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=TLGG9A81gaxbq3wwODEwMjAyMw&start=200" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIaQZ.png)

How do I have it work here? https://jsfiddle.net/n0rxfzag/

This is the javascript player, it's not working.

```
 function addPlayer(video) {
const options = {
  height: 360,
  host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
  width: 640,
  start:200
};
options.playerVars = {
  autoplay: 0,
  cc_load_policy: 0,
  controls: 1,
  disablekb: 1,
  fs: 0,
  iv_load_policy: 3,
  listType: "playlist",
  list: "TLGG9A81gaxbq3wwODEwMjAyMw",
};
options.events = {
  "onReady": onPlayerReady
};
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm5m1.png)

I added `start:200` to the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start: 200` should add to `playerVars`:

```
    options.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      listType: "playlist",
      list: "TLGG9A81gaxbq3wwODEwMjAyMw",
      start: 200,
    };
```

In function `shufflePlaylist`:

```
  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    //player.playVideoAt(0);
    //player.pauseVideo();
  }
```

Aslo you can try function [seekTo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#seekTo)